# Customized enumerate items

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I want to write following on my latex. Please help me.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeglossaries
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remk}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{assump}{Assumptions}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.3in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\begin{document}\begin{theorem}
If the $(k\times 1)$ vector $\bm{x}$ is distributed normally with mean vector $\bm{\mu}$ and variance-covariance matrix $\bm{I}_k$, then
\begin{enumerate}[(i).]
\item $\mathbb{E}[\phi(\bm{x}'\bm{x})\bm{x}]=\bm{\mu}\mathbb{E}[\phi(\chi^{2}_{(k+2,\Delta)})]$,
\item $\mathbb{E}[\phi(\bm{x}'\bm{x})\bm{x}\bm{x}']=\bm{I}_{k}\mathbb{E}[\phi(\chi^{2}_{(k+2,\Delta)})]+\bm{\mu}\bm{\mu}'\mathbb{E}[\phi(\chi^{2}_{(k+4,\Delta)})]$
\end{enumerate}
where $\Delta=\frac{1}{2}\bm{\mu}'\bm{\mu}$ is the noncentrality parameter.
\end{theorem}
 \begin{assump}[Regularity Conditions]
\begin{enumerate}[start=0,label={(\bfseries R\arabic*):}]
\begin{enumerate}
\item The pdfs are distinct.
\item The pdfs have common support for all $\theta$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{assump}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have created an Assumptions environment using \newtheorem but I am unable to start from the next line and to create a custom items numbers starting from zero.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without further information this is a starter...(I've not done the theorem environment around the enumeration)

The [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package is the key for easy customization of itemize/enumerate lists. It provides the means for use a starter value (`start=0`) and the `label=....` option.

`enumitem` can be used together or *as* `enumerate` using the `shortlabels` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

% Traditional style
\begin{enumerate}[a)] 
\item This is
\item an easy
\item customization of standard enumerate
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[start=0,label={(\bfseries R\arabic*):}]
\item This is
\item an easy
\item customization of enumerate
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KashifAli: That's why I asked about the MWE ;-) Now this leaves my work useless :-(

Comment: @KashifAli That is not an MWE. Please read the link Christian Hupfer provided. An MWE is a complete small document.

Comment: @KashifAli `enumitem` can emulate `enumerate`, can't it? So can't you just switch?

Comment: @KashifAli: Ok, but consider to clean up your document. The `\setlength` statements look a little bit strange. I suggest to use the `geometry` package. Happy TeXing! ;-)

Comment: Why the second one has a bad indentation? I tried it but as you also showed, it has a negative indentation. It is not aligned with the rest of the text.

Answer (score 7):

As there remains some problems with the placement of labels, I propose a variant that looks more like the image in the O.P.'s post. I replaced `amsthm` with `ntheorem`, which has a `break` theorem style and writes the optional argument of theorems in boldface if \theoremname is boldface.

Loading `mathdesign` did nothing, as no font was chosen as an option. I added `charter`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
%\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
%\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
%\newtheorem{remk}{Remark}[section]
%\newtheorem{assump}{Assumptions}[section]
%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

  \usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}

 \theoremstyle{plain}
 \theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
 \theorembodyfont{\itshape}
 \theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remk}{Remark}[section]

\theoremstyle{break}
 \theoremseparator{.\medskip}
\newtheorem{assump}{Assumptions}[section]

 \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
 \theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
 \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
 \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
 \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.3in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{section}{1}
\begin{theorem}
  If the $(k \times 1)$ vector $\bm{x}$ is distributed normally with mean vector $\bm{\mu}$ and variance-covariance matrix $\bm{I}_k$, then
  \begin{enumerate}[(i).]
    \item $\mathbb{E}[\phi(\bm{x}'\bm{x})\bm{x}]=\bm{\mu}\mathbb{E}[\phi(\chi^{2}_{(k+2,\Delta)})],$

    \item $\mathbb{E}[\phi(\bm{x}'\bm{x})\bm{x}\bm{x}'] = \bm{I}_{k}\mathbb{E}[\phi(\chi^{2}_{(k+2,\Delta)})] + \bm{\mu}\bm{\mu}'\mathbb{E}[\phi(\chi^{2}_{(k+4,\Delta)})],$
  \end{enumerate}
  where $\Delta=\frac{1}{2}\bm{\mu}'\bm{\mu}$ is the noncentrality parameter.
\end{theorem}

\begin{assump}[Regularity Conditions]
  \begin{enumerate}[start=0,label={\upshape(\bfseries R\arabic*):},wide = 0pt, leftmargin = 3em]
    \item The pdfs are distinct; i.e., $ \theta \neq \theta' \Rightarrow f(x_i; \theta) \neq f(x_i; \theta')$. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
    \item The pdfs have common support for all $\theta$.
    \item The point $ \theta_0$ is an interior point of $ \Omega $.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{assump}
\end{document}
```

[image]